# Symantec backupexec troubleshooting issues with a Dell Robotic tape Library in Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, backupexec, scsi, symantec

I’m running Symantec BackupExec 12.0 on a Windows 2003 server. After I powered down my SCSI tape drive (Dell PowerVault 124t autoloader) it no longer shows up in Backup Exec in the device pool. 
  So far, I have

- updated firmware on the tape unit
- reloaded drivers
- walked through the wizards in BUE
- updated patches on BUE
- restarted the server and the tape drive
- updated all drivers to the latest versions
- prayed
- run every utilities known top man.

Device manager shows the Tape unit is working properly and so is the SCSI Raid controller. I have walked through all of the tech notes from Symantec and other support blogs. I remember about a year ago I had this same problem and Symantec did a webex and repaired it. I think (cough cough) that they deleted some files and touched up the registry. I really can't remember. What else can I try to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you connected to the Autoloader's web console? You may be able to find an error code in the logs to point you in the right direction. I'm assuming you're using the LTO-3 version, so this doc may help: http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/stor-sys/124t/en/124tlto3/rmu.htm

Comment: Thank you for your posts, but it looks as if the Data back was the problem. I had Veritas remotely login and ran the BeUtility.exe that is located in your Symantec directory. Before you begin, find the folder that is named Data and make a backup copy of it. Right click on the server, in the dropdown menu do the following. verify, rebuild, compressed, and restore the database. Changed all BackupExe serivices to the local Administrator account. This will remove all AD permissions issues.

Answer (score 1):

You mention reloading drivers, but have you tried deleting the devices from device manager, rebooting and letting Windows reinstall? This has fixed me up a few times before.

If the autoloader is still under support, try giving Dell a call as they do have support staff with experience in BackupExec.

I assume from your posting here that you're out of maintenance with Symantec themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Tape drive doesn't bade well with RAID controller.

Some time slower that normal, some time doesn't work at all.

In some case, tape written on such drive can't even be read by another drive (block size changed on the fly).

Tape drive and tape library works perfectly fine with entry base controller...no need to use enhanced controller as RAID one, It's a bad idea in the end.